# Charles Proxy Will Not Open on Mac OS Catalina (10.15)

Tags: android, charles-proxy

I recently installed Charles Proxy on Mac OS Catalina.
I previously had a working version installed pre-Catalina.

The new version installs, and opens, but never fully launches. Instead, it is stuck on this screen: ["Configuring Proxies".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmiZi.png)

Any thoughts on how I can get it running again? I believe all previous installation files have been removed from my machine, but I may be missing something.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a question for Charles support rather than stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue.

With Charles v4.5.1, I was never prompted to grant access to proxies on MacOS. Having uninstalled Charles and re-installed the latest version (v4.5.4), I was prompted to grant this permission.

Charles is now up and running again.